# SQL: How can I speed up this select distinct query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm currently porting an application from Oracle to PostgresSQL.  I've got the same issue with Oracle, and this seems like a good time to try and fix this.

Anyway, I have a table with around 200M rows adding 100k rows/day that looks like this:

```
create table T1(
  id bigserial primary key,
  a integer,
  b char(5),
  c char(2),
);
```

Now, every now and then I need to know what the set of unique A, B, C vales are, so we see a query that looks kind of like this.  I think the table joins are largely irrelevant to the problem but I'm including them for completeness.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, C, T3.N 
     FROM T1
     JOIN T2 ON T2.ID = T1.A AND T2.NAME = 'FOO'
     JOIN T3 ON T3.ID = T2.PID
```

Also an index that looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX I ON T1(A,B,C);
```

The index speeds things up already since it allows for an index scan instead of a table scan.

This query usually takes about a minute or so and returns less than 100 rows.  I'd like for it to take about a millisecond.  I think the naive solution is create a new table just for keeping track of these values, then when adding a new record to T1 just check for the A,B,C tuple in there and add a new record if its missing which is an extremely rare event.  This seems like a hassle and there must be a better way than using two tables.

Using a GROUP BY trick doesn't help much if at all, as one might expect, since it still is scanning the entire index either way.

The query plan looks something like this:

[image]

We can see that the expression in the T2 join helps quite a bit as it filters huge chunks of the index on T1, as expected.

Comment: Can you share query plan also as per your assumption that joins are irrelevant may not be true. If seeing actual query plan then can probably get a better answer.

Comment: Added query plan.  As you can see T2 and T3 are very tiny.  T2.ID and T3.ID are primary keys.   (Also this is test data and the T1 is ~45M rows).

Comment: Have you tried [Materialized Views](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-materializedviews.html) option also?

Comment: Haven't tried a materialized view.  Looks feasible as I'm fine with rebuilding it once a day or once per hour to pick up new tuples.

Comment: Yeah, please show us your `explain (analyze, buffers) select ...`

Comment: Also, make sure that you did `ANALYZE` for all your tables before you play with queries.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the use of more indexes.  Insure you have an index for every way that you link to data.

For example you link to t2 on T2.ID.  So make sure you have an index on just T2.id not a composite index.

Generally it is faster to star with the table that you are filtering on.  You are filtering on T2.NAME = 'FOO' and you are using inner joins.

So start with T2, join to T1, and then to T3.

Also put an index on T3 on T3.ID, and another index on T1.A.

This will restrict the number of rows the query has to find.  It will only link to T3 and T1 for records in T2 that are NAME = 'FOO'.  Thus significanly reducing the total work load on the query.

Comment: This is a bunch of random advices that won't help: "put an index on T3 on T3.ID" -- it's already indexes (see "index only scan"),  " another index on T1.A" -- useless, it's already indexed (we have index on `(A,B,C)`, so we don't need a separate index on `a`).

Comment: You should check to see if your query is using the index that you think it is using.  I think you may have an error in this thinking.  Make sure all joins use indexes.